# Is the raspberry pi 3 memory byte addressible or word addressable and if it is word addressable what is the word size

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi3, cpu-architecture, addressing-mode

I am new to the raspberry pi 3 I wanted to ask a question related to the memory architecture of raspberry pi 3 my question is as follows

Is the raspberry pi 3 memory byte addressable or word addressable and if it is word addressable what is the word size in bytes

Comment: Are you asking about memory alignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspberry pi has nothing to do with this unless you are talking about the GPU.  It is just another arm.  How many word addressable instruction sets do you know about, in mainstream processors like arm?  Operating system (linux, bsd, etc) capable operating system processors like arm?

arms definition of the size of a word is in the arm documentation.

```
void fun ( unsigned char *p, unsigned char x, unsigned int z )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    for(ra=0;ra<z;ra++) p[ra]=x;
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3520000    cmp r2, #0
   4:   012fff1e    bxeq    lr
   8:   e0802002    add r2, r0, r2
   c:   e4c01001    strb    r1, [r0], #1
  10:   e1500002    cmp r0, r2
  14:   1afffffc    bne c <fun+0xc>
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

and there is your answer, is it using word addressing to fill the array or byte based?